# Sorting feature class to calculate sequential ID field using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I am in ArcMap and I want to sort the records based on a field and then do a Calculate Field with an auto-incrementing value with the sort in-place. Any ideas?

It looks like I could get an update cursor on the feature class then do an auto-increment, but I would still like to see if there is a way to do this in the Field Calculator in ArcMap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used ModelBuilder and I did a field sort followed by calculate field using the sort code below and it worked great.

Previously, I had tried these two steps outside of ModelBuilder and it failed.

Expression:

```
autoIncrement()
```

Expression Type:
PYTHON_9.3

Code Block:

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
    global rec
    pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
    pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
    if (rec == 0): 
        rec = pStart 
    else: 
        rec = rec + pInterval 
    return rec
```

Answer (score 12):

Try using [Sort (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000057000000) followed by [Calculate Field (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004m000000) using the auto-increment example on the [Calculate Field examples](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002m000000.htm) help page.

If you need to sort the data and update it in-place (no intermediate dataset), then I think you would have to use an [UpdateCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003m000000) which can also sort by a field.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  And if you need to do this on a recurring basis, consider linking these tools together in ModelBuilder.

Comment: The ESRI sample for sequential numbering is based on the FID (original row ID). I want the numbering to be based on the current sort -can this be done? In the code from ESRI what is "global" rec? Thanks.

Comment: My answer hopefully already answers your first question in two ways: 1) use Sort (Data Management), or 2) use an UpdateCursor with the sort fields argument. I do not think you can access the current table view's sort state through arcpy, though it may be possible through ArcObjects. As for your second question, `global` makes the variable persist between calculations (one calculation per row) so that it can store the running count used in each calculation.

Comment: Rather than using the global variable based increment example, you could use `itertools.count` [generator](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/57412/2856).