# Polyline to points ordered in cumulative distance from starting point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3

I have a problem with converting a line to points, where the points are ordered as the cumulative distance from the start of the line. I originally had 3 individual lines which I merged to make 1 continuous line using the `Dissolve` tool in ArcMap. However, it appears that the new line kept the features of the individual lines, because when I use the `Divide` function in `Editor` to create evenly spaced points along my 'merged' line, the points are ordered hap-hapzardly.

I am seeking a way to create points from that 'merged' line so that the points are ordered as incremental distances from the start of the line. It would be rather easy if the line were straight, however it meanders, therefore just ordering the points in ascending order (based on X or Y value) would not suffice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a multi part feature. You could try to explode them into single parts then merge them back together. The explode tool is on the advance editing tool bar and the merge option is under the main editor menu on the editor tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

the tool "repair geometry" is supposed to reorder the vertices.

Comment: Thanks radiuxju, gave it a try. Although it successfully repaired the geometry, it still did not solve the problem. I even tried `feature to points` ..

Comment: Strange : it works with me. But I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and it sounds like you are using ArcGIS 9.x (divide is called "construct point"), so I cannot test it on my computer. Maybe your merged lines are not perfectly coïncident. You can check this by clicking on the "sketch properties" icon after selecting your feature in an editing session (see if you have several parts). The "integrate" tool could then help you to merge nearly coincident vertices in a given tolerance http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=integrate_%28data_management%29

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are right. Using ArcGIS 9.3. I They aren't coincident. By chance, would you happen to know if is there a tool to order generated points from left to right on the x-plane? I generated points from the different segments, but going through point by point, I am realizing that the points don't follow any particular order.

Comment: an illustration would be usefull. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: as for your question, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16752/how-to-sort-a-feature-class-and-then-calculate-a-sequential-id-field (using calculate geometry for the X coordinate)