# Re-numbering points along a polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, point, line

Using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

I created perpendicular lines along a polyline.  In the process of doing that, the lines were numbered in order (automatically).  I manually edited some of the perpendicular lines which re-assigned them a number and therefore the ID's aren't increasing numerically in order along the polyline.  I then used the interesect tool to create a point at the intersection of each perpendicular line along the polyline.  I want to create a polyline from these data points, but since the id's are not in numeric order the line is not being created correctly.

Question:
How can I assign a number to a data point that increases as the points move along the polyline?

I have also tried using ET Geowizards but I don't have a full license and am limited to 100 points but this data set is approximately 20,000 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple work around:

Use ET Geowizards - Points - Create Station Points to station the line in increments smaller than the distance between data points.  The created points (Sample1) will be in numerical order.

Join (using spatial location) the Sample1 data points to the data set that you want to re-order.  For question 2 in dialog box, choose "Each will be given all the attributes..."

Now all of the data points can be sorted by the new objectID field and will be in order as you move along the polyline.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [linear referencing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000002000000) to extract the position of the points along the lines ("locate along route" tool).

Then you sort your point using these values and [compute an incremental integer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16752/how-to-sort-a-feature-class-and-then-calculate-a-sequential-id-field).

Comment: Radouxja- I have tried the linear referencing procedure that you have described above.  I have 22,324 data points along the route, however, when I use the "locate along route" tool, the resulting table only has 1,812 data points.  I need information for each point.  Do you know how to work around this?