# Can ArcGIS geoprocessing tools be used in ArcGIS Field calculator?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, arcgis-10.4

Can you put ArcGIS geoprocessing tools such as `arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management()` or `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management()` into the code block of the ArcGIS Field-calculator (ArcGIS Desktop 10.4)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What happened when you tried to do this?

Comment: 99% possible, similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193681/calculating-sequential-numbers-into-sorted-table-using-arcgis-desktop/193684#193684

Comment: @FelixIP do you think it is a duplicate or mind answering this?

Comment: @fatih_dur I'll give it go, because it is not exactly duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generated random points inside 4 polygons shapefile, using field "Points_Cnt". The source of polygons is "C:\FELIX_DATA\SCRARCH\fish_net.shp":

[image]

The result of this field caluclator expression on a new field "RESULT":

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
LR=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
d=arcpy.Describe(LR)
def getPoints(fid):
 arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management ("C:/FELIX_DATA/SCRARCH/fish_net.shp","A",'"FID" ='+str(fid))
 arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(LR,"INTERSECT","A")
 nSel=len(d.FIDset.split(';'))
 return nSel
```

## --------------------

```
getPoints( !FID!)
```

[image]

Confirms that it is possible to use tools in field calculator.

Comment: After posting solution I realized, that OP is not so weird. It is a very cool way to count points in polygons without need of spatial join, summary statistics and attribute join ! No need to clean intermediate Results.

Comment: Ah, I just realized how you used the fid in a where_clause to select a single object for the feature class. That is useful. As per you hint in: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261584/using-selectlayerbylocation-management-parameters).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be done with some of the geoprocessing tools.

Proof of concept - use `arcpy.GetCount_management()` to count the selected features and write that value to those selected features:

```
def myTest():
    count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management('testPoint').getOutput(0))
    return count
```

[image]

Another, use `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management()` to select every ObjectID divisible by `4` and write a value to those newly selected features:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('testPoint','NEW_SELECTION','mod(OBJECTID,4)=0')
def myTest():
    return 123
```

[image]

Of course you can make these more complex if you require, however I would recommend using arcpy script tools and update cursors if you're getting too clever, rather than Field Calculator.