# Calculate sequential ID field using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

In this example, previously posted as [Calculating sequential numbers into sorted table using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/193681/115) :

How do you construct a Python code that would give the Seq field sequencing such as:

```
1963.......1
1963.......1
1965.......2
1966.......3
1967.......4
1967.......4
1967.......4
1968.......5
```

Etc....   ???

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding questions here are expected to contain code. You reference "previously posted" without a link. Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: @Charles, hey do you want the `Seq` field to be unique or you want it to be based on the `Year` field (that is all 1963 years will have 1 in the `Seq` and all 1965 will have 2 in the `Seq`)? In the question body you duplicate values, but in the screenshot you don't, I am puzzled.

Comment: I would like it to be based on the year field but same year should have the same seq value.

Comment: This references: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193681/calculating-sequential-numbers-into-sorted-table-using-arcgis-desktop

Comment: You could create a csv file with two columns (**Years** and corresponding **Seq** codes - a couple of minutes in a spreadsheet). Read the csv file into a python dictionary with **Years** as keys and **Seq** code as values. With the update cursor you can write the right **Seq** value for the corresponding **Year** into your feature table.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the attribute values for a given feature, and then do the following field calculator operation for all features:

Seq = Year - (year zero)

So for your example it would be Seq = Year - 1962

These two pages for ArcGIS for Desktop and ArcGIS Pro have further details on how to do this and other field calculator operations, including some example python scripts.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm

Comment: Can you give a few more details on where you're getting stuck? This page has a lot more specific syntax details on arcpy.CalculateField_management() http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm

Comment: How do you construct a code to accomplish the pattern above, where for the same year value, Seq value is the same but for the next year it updates bu an increment of 1, etc?

Comment: That's the whole idea behind subtracting the year zero value. In your example: 1963 - 1962 = 1, 1964 - 1962 = 2, 1965-1962 = 3, etc. Although now I take a second look your example doesn't do this exactly (differently in the text and the picture). Are you intentionally skipping 1964=2, or is that a typo?

Comment: No; and would the sequence be the same for each occurrence of say 1967, etc.?

Comment: The OP is confusing because the two images are inconsistent: in the first example Seq increments by one only  when Year changes, but in the second example Seq increments for each record.