# Calculating frequency in Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, frequency

I have a table with many instances of duplicate values.

My end goal is to have three columns:

- `"The Value"`: a file name. most are non-unique
- `"Duplicate Instance"`: "this is the 1st time this file name appears in the list", the 2nd, the 3rd, etc.
- `"Total count of Duplicates"`: "this file name appears 5 times in this list"

I have the  Duplicate Instance from [@FelixP's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/34531/felixip) answer to [Auto incrementing field based on groups within feature class?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154)

I can create a separate frequency table with the [Frequency](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/frequency.htm) tool then join that table to calculate in the total count of each file name, but **I would love to skip a few steps and directly calculate the frequency in the Field Calculator interface.**

Is it possible to directly calculate frequency in ArcGIS Desktop Field Calculator?

Comment: Does it have to be Field Calculator or can it be with code in python window?

Comment: good point for clarification. I'd like to keep it set it up for use in the Field Calculator's "Pre-Logic Script Code" interface.

Comment: I doubt it is possible. You will have to iterate over / field calculate all rows twice and somehow save the results from first iteration and use in second. Using python window is it easier

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case - that any solution would need to  but be unable to iterate through again. Still hopeful that someone might have some field calculator magic to share, though!

Comment: Similarly to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193681/calculating-sequential-numbers-into-sorted-table-using-arcgis-desktop/193684#193684 you can go twice, however result goes to 1 field, you need 2 of them. So - script or 2 field calculations.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't find a solution using Field Calculator try python window with [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and two da.UpdateCursors:

```py
import arcpy
from collections import Counter

fc = 'C:\data.gdb\my_riks' #Change
values = 'KKOD' #Change
dupinst = 'dupinst' #Change
totcount = 'totcount' #Change

cnt = Counter()

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [values, dupinst]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cnt[row[0]] += 1
        row[1] = cnt[row[0]]
        cursor.updateRow(row)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [values, totcount]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = cnt[row[0]]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Field Calculator only iterates once over the table so you cannot generate a frequency list and apply it with one pass.  If this is a task you need to repeat I'd recommend using a python script outside Field Calculator or creating a model in ModelBuilder.