# Only display Top 10% of values ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, display

I have a field called "Values" in ArcMap where I am just wanting to Display the 10% of the values on the map and the remainder of the values not be shown on the map.

Is there a way I can do this?
I was thinking perhaps I could do a selection? Select the top 10% values in the field?

Comment: Set a definition query

Comment: Compute new field using descending order, e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193681/calculating-sequential-numbers-into-sorted-table-using-arcgis-desktop/193684#193684 and use definition query. Or create a sorted copy of dataset.

Comment: Yes can do new field descending order but I'm stuck on what the formula is for top 10% in definrion query ?

Comment: I.e i can calculate the 10th percentile but not the top 10% for my range.

Comment: How do you calculate top 10%?

Comment: Formulae is simple, number of records/10. So if you have 200 records, everything in new field < 21 is your answer. You forget @ before user name, if you'd like him/her to hear you.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple to do if your feature class is in a sql geodatabase - you can just set a definition query to select literally just the top 10 percent of values:

```sql
Value IN (SELECT TOP(10) PERCENT Value from gisse.DBO.MyPoints order by Value Desc)
```

just change `Value` to your field name (it appears 3 times in the code above), and change the `gisse.DBO.MyPoints` to reference your data source.

---

On the other hand, if your feature class is in a file geodatabase it's a bit more complicated, but it can be done.  The way I did it is as follows:

I created a new field called TenPC and opened the Field Calculator

[image]

Select the Python Parser and click on "Show Codeblock" and use add this code:

```py
x = "MyPoints"
f = "Value"
tpc = (int(arcpy.GetCount_management(x)[0])/10) + 1
y = list()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(x,f) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        y.append(row[0])
z = sorted(y,reverse=True)[:tpc]

def top_ten_pc(fieldval):
    if fieldval in z:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And this expression:

```py
top_ten_pc(!Value!)
```

Changing `x = "MyPoints"` to reference your *layer*, and `f = "Value"` to reference the field name you're filtering on, and `!Value!` to also reference the field name.

[image]

Click OK to calculate the field.  Now in your new field you should see lots of `0` and `1` values.  Any feature with a `1` is in your top 10 percent of values.

[image]

You can now write a definition query to display only these features

```sql
TenPC = 1
```

Note - my Python is very rusty and I may be overthinking this, so there may be far more efficient ways to do what I've described above!