# Naming Points Along Line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, route, naming-conventions

I have a line with several points along it. I am hoping to name these points numerically, from 1 to the last point along the line.

I've so far used Network Analyst to find my distance along the line for all points and given myself a way to organize it by location. What I am attempting to do here is name them "1, 2, 3, 4..." etc. from start to finish, but am not sure how.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193681/calculating-sequential-numbers-into-sorted-table-using-arcgis-desktop/193684#193684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten around this by editing the table in Excel. I sorted by the Measure field, then added sequential numbering. I then used Join to add these sequential numbers to the shapefile.