# Sequence of Numbers using the field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

I have an issue with my code. I am using ArcMap 10.8 and I am trying to create a sequence of numbers, taking into account one sorted field (the field "Latitude"). My code is the following one:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Operating.mxd") #Pre-Logic Script Code: Set the mxd to be used`

lr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0] #Specify that the target layer is the first layer in the table of conten
tbl=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(lr,("Label","Latitude"))    
       
bs=sorted(tbl,key=lambda x: x[1])                                                 
aDict={}

for i,row in enumerate(bs):
    aDict[row[0]]=i+1
def sortSeq(Label):
    return aDict[Label]                                                                     
sortSeq(!Label!) #Expression #to run the code, the following goes in the expression window`
```

Despite that the first time the code worked, when I repeated the process, it gives me an error that refers to the following (attached screenshot).[image: attached screenshot]

Comment: What does the geoprocessing result window report?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing a sample of the attribute table and your expected result?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find a way to add a screenshot of the desired result. I want an attribute table that will have sequential values, just like the post from the previous year (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193681/calculating-sequential-numbers-into-sorted-table-using-arcgis-desktop). As for the received error, I change the code a little bit, setting at the 4rth line: bs=sorted(tbl,key=lambda x: x[0], x[1]), because it referred that there was an issue with the number of parameters. But right now it shows me that there is an issue with the line 11 (error 000539).

Comment: Thanks, @BERA. I will do it that way!