# Converting points to line using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.7

I am using Points To Line in ArcMap , to join with a line each point. But the final point returns to the first point.

How can I do the line without come back to the first point?

I made a column with the day that would be from 1 to 31 (august) to be as a group and the other column I used the ID from 1 to the end.

[image: example of the table]

[image: example of point to lines]

Comment: If didn't pick 'close line' number your points and delete last one https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193681/calculating-sequential-numbers-into-sorted-table-using-arcgis-desktop#193684 which will become first if sorted in descending order.

Comment: Thank FelixIP fot the answer, at the end I created a new column grouping the points that are equal  to a line, and it worked.