# Adding sequential number's to a Field in ArcGIS Pro not based on Object ID number

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, numbering, sequential

I simply want to add a Field to an existing attribute table in ArcGIS Pro and sequentially number this field (e.g. record 1 will show the number 1, record 2 will show number 2, record 3 will show number 3, etc. until all the records have a number.

I've tried the sequential number expression using Calculate Field but it uses the ObjectID field. I do NOT want to reference the ObjectID field. Due to an Append followed by a Sort done on a Field other than the ObjectID field, I can't have the sequential numbers generated in the new field based on the ObjectID.

Is there a way to do this? Or should I just export the table to Excel where I know I can enter number 1 into the top record, number 2 into the record that is the 2nd record, 3 into the third record and then just drag downward and the program enters sequential numbers until I get to the bottom of the file. Is then have to export the spreadsheet back to ArcGIS Pro and add xy's.  But I can't believe there isn't any way to just add a Field info Pro and generate sequential numbers but Not based on the ObjectID.

Comment: Never export out to Excel, that's just crazy! Either use @BERA solution or if you still want to run it as a field calculator tool use the sample code [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F3F8CD77A9F647ABBA678A76ADB86E15).

Comment: Keep in mind that different sources might produce a different values, and that the row order might be different (unique, but not necessarily sequential in any specific block of data).

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193681/calculating-sequential-numbers-into-sorted-table-using-arcgis-desktop#193684